# How to pipe find results to unzip?

Tags: linux, tcsh

I have a lot of folders with a zip file in each. Most of the zip files in the folders have been opened already. I just want to unzip those which have not been opened, which I know all have the same date.

I'm trying to use the following but I'm getting hit back with Unzip rules. The first part finds all the files I need, but piping the results to unzip, as I have done, isn't enough.

```
find *2019-01-05* | unzip
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `xargs` to get prior results and then `unzip` them:

```
find *2019-01-05* | xargs unzip
```

Answer (score 0):

That's:

```
find -type f -name \*2019-01-05\*.zip -exec unzip {} +
```

`-type f` for good measure, in case there are similarly named directories.